# Initialize program in bashrc

Tags: software-installation, bashrc

I am in the process of installing Anaconda in Debian. Then I get the following prompt:

```
...
installation finished.
Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3
in your /home/isnani/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
[no] >>>
```

What if I choose `yes`? What does `initialize something in ../.bashrc` mean?

Comment: It probably sets or modifies some environment variables.

Comment: Make a backup copy of your `.bashrc` and respond "yes" to the prompt. Then `diff` the old and new `.bashrc` to see what was modified.

Answer (score 2):

Type yes so that you can use the conda command. In order to activate the installation, you should source the ~/.bashrc file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```